# Doxygen detailed description bleeds into the brief description

Tags: c++, doxygen

My doxygen for the following code shows up like this:

`Spawns two mettaurs on the fieldMay optionally spawn an empty tile for challenge`

Where the brief description should be. Notice it's merging the brief and the detailed description.

```
/*! \brief Spawns two mettaurs on the field
 *  \class TwoMettaurMob
 * 
 * May optionally spawn an empty tile for challenge
 */

#pragma once
#include "bnMobFactory.h"
#include "bnMettaur.h"
#include "bnMettaurIdleState.h"

class TwoMettaurMob :
  public MobFactory
{
public:
  TwoMettaurMob(Field* field);
  ~TwoMettaurMob();

  /**
   * @brief Builds and returns the mob
   * @return Mob pointer. must be deleted manually.
   */
  Mob* Build();
};
```

I'm following doxygen's example for doc blocks:

```
/*! \brief Brief description.
 *         Brief description continued.
 *
 *  Detailed description starts here.
 */
```

Anyone know a solution?

Comment: Have you tested adding an "empty" line directly after the brief description? I.e. between the two lines `\brief` and `\class`.

Comment: Which version of doxygen are you using?

Comment: I'm using the latest doxygen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could reproduce the problem with the current (1.8.15) version of doxygen.

The solution of @Someprogrammerdude does work

The order of commands is a bit strange I would have expected first the `\class` followed by the `\brief` description, also the `\class` is not necessary as the documentation is (in this case) directly in front of the class.

Another solution is to place a `.` at the end of the sentence and have `JAVADOC_AUTOBRIEF` or `QT_AUTOBRIEF` set to `YES`.

The background of the problem is that `\class` is not seen as a ending the `\brief` documentation. It might be worthwhile to submit an issue report at https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/new (so either it can be fixed or some extra objections can be given against using `\class`, and others with similar meaning, for terminating a brief description.

Comment: This was flagged as a bug and ended up promoting some new feature requests. Take a look:

https://github.com/doxygen/doxygen/issues/6945

Comment: The mentioned feature request has been integrated into the master branch of doxygen.